# How to get rid of the parenthesis and comma in my output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a code in python where I use different functions to calculate wage, federal tax, state tax, and net worth. Everything is fine except my output says, `('Your wage is: $', 989)` instead of `Your wage is: $989` I tried using `+(wag)` but it doesn't let me run it. How do I get rid of the parenthesis, comma, and quotation marks from the output? And how do I make the output have no decimal points? I am not using float, so I don't know why it's still giving me decimal points. Here's my code:

```
def Calculatewages():
    wage = (work*hours)
    return wage
def CalcualteFederaltax():
    if (status== ("Married")):
        federaltax = 0.20
    elif (status== ("Single")):
        federaltax = 0.25
    elif status:
        federaltax = 0.22
    federaltax = float(wag*federaltax)
    return federaltax
def Calculatestatetax():
    if(state=="CA") or (state=="NV") or (state=="SD") or (state=="WA") or (state=="AZ"):
        statetax = 0.08
    if (state== "TX") or(state=="IL") or (state=="MO") or (state=="OH") or (state=="VA"):
        statetax = 0.07
    if (state== "NM") or (state== "OR") or (state=="IN"):
        statetax = 0.06
    if (state):
        statetax = 0.05
    statetax = float(wag*statetax)
    return statetax
def Calculatenet():
    net = float(wag-FederalTax-StateTax)
    return net

hours = input("Please enter your work hours: ")
work = input("Please enter your hourly rate: ")
state = input("Please enter your state of resident: ")
status = input("Please enter your marital status: ")
print("**********")
wag = Calculatewages()
FederalTax = CalcualteFederaltax()
StateTax = Calculatestatetax()
Net = Calculatenet()
print("Your wage is: $" ,wag)
print("Your federal tax is: $",FederalTax)
print("Your state tax is: $",StateTax)
print("Your net wage is: $",Net)
```

Comment: Did it successfully run? How do you know there is paranthesis and comma in output without actually seeing the output?

Comment: You think you're on Python 3, but that output says you're not.

Comment: @Austin I ran it on c9.io which is a website my teacher provided, and it works, but just has parenthesis, commas, and quotation marks for some weird reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this part:

```
print("Your wage is: $" ,wag)
print("Your federal tax is: $",FederalTax)
print("Your state tax is: $",StateTax)
print("Your net wage is: $",Net)
```

you can rewrite it as this using string's format() method:

```
print("Your wage is: ${}".format(wag))
print("Your federal tax is: ${}".format(FederalTax))
print("Your state tax is: ${}".format(StateTax))
print("Your net wage is: ${}".format(Net))
```

This is useful as you can insert the value into any place in the string (wherever you put the curly brackets).

As for your decimal points problem you can use the built in round function like this:

```
round(float(variable), int(decimal_places))
```

for example:

```
round(1.43523556, 2)
```

will return 1.44

Answer (score 2):

There are no quotes or parenthesis in the output in `python 3.x`, Check if you are running on `python 2` or `python 3`. Looks like you are on `python 2` by judging your output.

So change  all your print statements like this

```
print "Your net wage is: $", wag # remove brackets
...
```

However, if you want it to run on python 3 your code doesn't run as you are multiplying 2 strings in this line

```
def Calculatewages():
    wage = (work*hours) # <------ here
    return wage
```

To fix this issue you must cast them into `int` and then your code should run without problems.

```
hours = int(input("Please enter your work hours: ")) # < ---- Cast to int
work = int(input("Please enter your hourly rate: ")) # < ---- Cast to int
state = input("Please enter your state of resident: ")
status = input("Please enter your marital status: ")
```

My output:

```
Please enter your work hours: 8
Please enter your hourly rate: 10
Please enter your state of resident: IN
Please enter your marital status: Single
**********
Your wage is: $ 80
Your federal tax is: $ 20.0
Your state tax is: $ 4.0
Your net wage is: $ 56.0
```

you can also use string's format() method:

```
print("Your wage is: ${}".format(wag))
print("Your federal tax is: ${}".format(FederalTax))
print("Your state tax is: ${}".format(StateTax))
print("Your net wage is: ${}".format(Net))
```

Comment: Oh ok I get it now, but do you know how to get rid of the space between `$` and the output number?

Comment: @H.Khan Remove the `$` from the print statement. `print "Your net wage is: ", wag` like this

Comment: Sorry I meant have it output `$20` instead of `$ 20.0`

Comment: Here's how you can do that, `print "Your net wage is: ${}".format(wag)`

Answer (score 0):

If you're running under python3.x, then with your code, it should print out without the parenthesis, and if you're running under python2.x, then to get rid of the parenthesis, you might wanna try:

print "Your wage is: $", wag